# Is it possible to order by a value which I dont want select in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to order values from database query by date but I want also to change their format

```
SELECT to_char( date, 'DD.MM.YYYY') "date1", date as date2
from ..

order by date2
```

This SQL has just one problem. I don't want date2 int the output.

Thanks for your help

Comment: remove `date as date2` from your select clause and yet your query will work..

Comment: @hudi A few people have hinted at the same answer now which is correct based on the question you have presented, if you are unclear then please amend your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
order by date
```

or

```
order by tableName.date
```

Comment: Just use 'order by tableName.date'. It will order by the real value in the table, not the formated one.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
SELECT to_char( date, 'DD.MM.YYYY') "date1"
from ..

order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT to_char( date, 'DD.MM.YYYY') "date1"
from ..

order by to_date(date,'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: when I convert date to string then it order by as string not date what I dont want. 1.3.2012 is before 27.2.2012 when it order by converted date to string

Comment: @hudi This method will work fine, you are only converting the output to a string, the order by is left in date format and so will sort correctly. If you mean you want to sort it as a string as well then use the same "To_char" statement in your order by as well as the select.

Comment: @Vikram: using to_date() on a date column is completely useless.

Comment: Not only useless as @a_horse_with_no_name stated, but also wrong, oracle will use nls_date_format to convert it to a string first which may not be in the right format

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you are running into is that the column is named `date`, which is an Oracle reserved word. If that is the case, you need to enclose it in quotes in order to avoid the error.

```
SELECT to_char( "DATE", 'DD.MM.YYYY') "date1"
from tablename
order by "DATE"
```